# Sfarim vs. Stand-alone sources

Tags: sources-mekorot, talmud-gemara, torah-study, adult-learning, chavrusa

BSD

I was learning with my Chavrusa the other day from a source sheet, and he displayed some surprise when I reached for the Sefer where the particular cited source was referenced. Upon asking why I did that, I said that I preferred to use Sfarim as opposed to just sources photocopied onto a sheet. He then asked why, to which I did not have a good answer. This got me thinking about this question and I haven't thought of a good answer, so I'm turning to you guys:

Why is it that some people to read things out of physical Sfarim as opposed to photocopied source pages?

Thanks!

Comment: Does this have anything to do with Judaism? Some people prefer paperbacks to Kindles.

Comment: Quite simply source sheets even photocopied dont usually have the full source. Usually only a single page of it.

Answer (score 3):

If you look up the quoted source, you can see whether the entire relevant part was quoted and (if not) what wasn't.